# Writing NetCDF time variable from start of year

Tags: python, netcdf

I'm writing a netCDF file and trying to create a time variable of seconds from the start of the year. I am writing this for a temperature variable that has values recorded every 6 hours for a year (1459 elements). How can I make a netCDF file that writes these two variables with time ranging from the start of the year and stepping every 6 hours?

```
if year_desired % 4 == 0:
ntime = 1462
else : ntime = 1458
n_air_temperature = np.reshape(air_temperature_opendap,(ntime,1,1))

# Assign the dimension data to the new NetCDF file.
ntime = int(ntime)
ncfile.createDimension('time',ntime)
ncfile.createDimension('latitude',1)
ncfile.createDimension('longitude',1)
air_temperature =    ncfile.createVariable('air_temperature',dtype('float32').char, ('time','latitude','longitude'))

air_temperature[21600::] = n_air_temperature

ncfile.close()
```

Comment: @MikeMüller just posted above

Comment: @James, I've noticed you've asked 7 questions yet have never accepted an answer. Please see, http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer. I understand my answer to this question may not have solved your problem (sorry I don't know netcdf). But some of your other questions have good answers that you should consider accepting.

Comment: @jimhark You did solve my problem! I apologize for not 'accepting' your answer, I am new to stacked. Thanks for the info!

Comment: @James, no worries. Thanks for accepting, I'm glad it helped. If you want, you have another opportunity to help other users by adding a note at the end of your question showing how the date manipulation fits into the netcdf code. (I have an idle curiosity about this myself.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You ask how to calculate:

> variable of seconds from the start of the year.

You can do that using:

```
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()
yearStart = datetime.datetime(now.year, 1, 1)
diffTime = now - yearStart
yearSeconds = int(diffTime.total_seconds())
```

You go on to ask about creating:

> temperature variable that has values recorded every 6 hours for a year (1459 elements).

You could convert the year seconds to your sample index using:

```
index = yearSeconds / (60*60*6) # / 60 sec/min * 60 min/hour * 6 hours
```

But then you want:

> time ranging from the start of the year and stepping every 6 hours

So maybe you need to go the other way. You have the index (sample number) and want the corresponding date. You can calculate that using:

```
sampleDateTime = yearStart + datetime.timedelta(0, index * 60 * 60 * 6)
```

Be sure you have set the correct yearStart for your data.